# How to move collapse icon from Left to right on Primefaces accordion

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Is there a way to move the open and close icon on accordion from left to right end.

Comment: Yes, there is :) Are you famliar with CSS? By the way, you can better post constructive questions along with own attempts instead of rhetorical or open ended questions which would only invite for downvotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I jut found the solution.

```
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header .ui-icon {
    margin-top: -8px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0.5em;
    top: 50%;
}
```